# Client id and secret key for each Customers instead of Users

Tags: laravel, api

I want to create an API for my web application. Actually i can create with JWT/Passport. I want to have separate Client ID and Secret keys for Customers. I have already installed to passport for this  but i am afraid if i change user_id to make customer_id may be i mess with laravel.

```
$this->schema->create('oauth_clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('secret', 100)->nullable();
            $table->string('provider')->nullable();
            $table->text('redirect');
            $table->boolean('personal_access_client');
            $table->boolean('password_client');
            $table->boolean('revoked');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Can i get any good idea for this how can i achieve this scenario?

Is this can be achieved using JWT Auth/Passport? Please suggest other package for this.

Any help?

Comment: do you want to use different personal_access_client each customer? For what? If just want to create Access Token for login, actually you can create token without define personal_access_client in each customer

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur i just want client id and secret key for each customer i dont want to use Users table

Comment: you can use client id and secret key to customer, user_id is nullable, the auto generate from `passport:install` doesnt use user_id

Comment: @MuhammadDyasYaskur i did the same but laravel passport user_id is mapped multiple places i hope you understand my query i mentioned in my post that i have used passport already

Answer (score 0):

try to use Laravel Sanctum. It is for APIs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

Comment: this doesnt provide client id and secret key .